# Caching to reduce load (PHP & MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, caching, memcached

im getting many hits from google, but its not like user gets always hits the same page. The user gets always a different page. So caching with memcached will not working i think cause the user reaches always a other page, which needs to generate and cached.

So would could i do to reduce the load from the server. I already implement sphinx search which helped me to reduce the load and the speed of the search page.

Any ideas to reduce the load?

Comment: can you totally cache the pages of your site? do user input any data to the pages?

Comment: for example i get many hits to search pages, so user inputs some data

Comment: you need fasten search? or server response in general?

Comment: search is already fast, takes 1 -2 second to load. I need faster server response and also decreasing my load. MY maschine is a dual core + 2GB ram

Answer (score 1):

- Use MySQL [partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html)
- Use opcode cacher (for example [eaccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/))
- Use nginx as front-end (for all static content), apache as back-end
- Maybe use some NoSQL decisions
- Setup your MySQL server in the right way(for [innodb](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/))
- I suggest use InooDB engine for tables with many rows
- Setup right index on tables
- MySQL [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)
- You could setup some limitation for search bot's

Comment: If you're a really heavily-trafficked site, and you set up nginx as your webserver, I am of the opinion that you might as well go the whole way and replace Apache for PHP processing with [php-fpm](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php). But other than that, I think this is a good list to get someone started (although a lot of it assumes you have a very large MySQL database... if you don't have many rows, you may not want to bother doing partitioning, for example).  If you can afford a second server, offloading MySQL to another server would help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well there two approaches to caching web applications

1. You cache the request, I mean using ob_start(), ob_flush(), etc you get the data to response, put this data to file and just response this file next time, you should take care of disk space and delete files using cron... ( benefits: decrease i/o operations and memory usage  )
2. You can cache aggregated data in order to prevent heavy aggregation next time...

choose))